# Finding a Maven dependency from a Javadoc

Tags: java, maven, javadoc

If I have a Javadoc, For example:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials.html

Is there a generic/standard way of finding what Maven dependency/JAR it belongs to?

Occasionally I'll come across auto-generated Javadocs with no comments and it can be tough to find the actual code. I'm guessing there's no intrinsic link between the Javadoc and the location of the build artifact, though I'd like to confirm that assumption.

In this particular case, I know that this class is contained in the following dependency from doing my own Googling.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.934</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually start from https://www.findjar.com/ ,   and then go with results to https://mvnrepository.com/

Comment: You can use central search like this: https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.sonatype.nexus makes it in one go. A click on the "Advances search" will show the explanation...